# Apache Axis failing handling Surrogate Pairs while creating a Soap Request

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, axis, utf-16

We have a Java program written to receive JSON and send a SoapRequest to an another backend.

My understanding is incoming JSON which is UTF-8 will be encoded in UTF-16 Java String (default) once program receives it.

Apache Axis library that we are using then take those UTF-16 Java Strings and try to covert back into UTF-8 to create a XML before sending to backend. It fails whenever I send a 4-byte Emoji (:grin:) UTF-8 character. I found that any UTF-8 4-byte character will be represented as surrogate pair in UTF-16. I suspect in that case Axis parser not able to understand surrogate pair and not able to convert into valid UTF-8 encoding.

Any one has seen something like this before? 
I have got this link which talking something similar. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC56808